# How to stop task servers in marklogic created by a particular user

Tags: marklogic

Below is the query I am using to stop taskservers:

```
xquery version "1.0-ml";

declare namespace ss = "http://marklogic.com/xdmp/status/server <http://marklogic.com/xdmp/status/server>;
declare namespace hs = "http://marklogic.com/xdmp/status/host"<http://marklogic.com/xdmp/status/host>;

let $taskServerId as xs:unsignedLong := xdmp:host-status(xdmp:host())//hs:task-server-id
for $i as xs:integer in (1 to 5400)
for $requestId as xs:unsignedLong in xdmp:server-status(xdmp:host(), $taskServerId)//ss:request-id/text()
return (
  try {
    xdmp:request-cancel(xdmp:host(), $taskServerId, $requestId)
  } catch ($e) {
    xdmp:log("Failed to cancel requests, retrying...")
  },
  xdmp:sleep(100)
)
```

Can anybody please help in getting only those task servers which are created by a particular user name?

Answer (score 3):

The XML output `xdmp:server-status` contains the user info you are looking for, so you can filter on that:

```
xquery version "1.0-ml";

declare namespace ss = "http://marklogic.com/xdmp/status/server";

let $user := xdmp:user("gjosten")
let $host := xdmp:host()
let $taskServer := xdmp:server('TaskServer')

for $i in (1 to 5400)
for $request in xdmp:server-status($host, $taskServer)
  //ss:request-status[ss:user = $user]/ss:request-id
return (
  try {
    xdmp:request-cancel($host, $taskServer, $request)
  } catch ($e) {
    xdmp:log("Failed to cancel requests, retrying...")
  },
  xdmp:sleep(100)
)
```

HTH!